# When I launch tmux in the terminal it shows this irritating gray bar. Is there way to remove it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, tmux

[image: terminal]

This gray bar says "amarbrkic@prometheus: ~80x24".

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with `tmux`, that is the default bar shown by the `terminator` terminal:

[image: screenshot of terminator, not running tmux but showing the same bar]

In the image above, I have simply launched `terminator`, without `tmux` or `screen` or anything else. As you can see, the bar is there.

To remove it, open terminal, right click on it and choose "preferences". Then, go to the "Profiles" tab, select your default profile and deselect the "Show titlebar" option:

[image: screenshot showing the relevant terminator option]